# A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderLimitedBox

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am using Silver Widget to show the list but its showing error

A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox

I think is some issue in stream builder, container and slivers?

This is my code.

```
class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {

  List<int>? separateItemQuantityList;
  num totalAmount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    totalAmount = 0;
    Provider.of<TotalAmount>(context, listen: false).displatTotalAmount(0);

    separateItemQuantityList = separateItemQuanties();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.cyan,
                  Colors.amber,
                ],
                begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              )
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear_all),
          onPressed: () {
            clearCartNow(context);
          },
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "FoodCode",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontFamily: "Concert",
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        actions: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.cyan,),
                onPressed: (){
                  // send user to cart screen
                  print("clicked");
                },
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 3,
                      right: 4,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Consumer<CartItemCounter>(
                          builder:(context, counter, c)
                          {
                            return Text(
                              counter.count.toString(),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: ()
              {
                clearCartNow(context);
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> SplashScreen()));
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Cart has been cleared.");
              },
              heroTag: null,
              label: const Text('Clear Cart', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: ()
              {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> AddressScreen(
                  totalAmount: totalAmount.toDouble(),
                  merchantUID: widget.merchantUID,
                )));
              },
              heroTag: null,
              label: const Text('Check Out', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [

          // overall total amount
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned:true,
            delegate: TextWidgetHeader(
                title: "My Cart List "
            ),
          ),

          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter>(builder: (context, amountProvider, cartProvider, c) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Center(
                  child: cartProvider.count == 0
                      ? Container()
                      : Text(
                    "Total Price: " + amountProvider.tAmount.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },),
          ),

          // display cart items with quantity
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("Items")
                .where("ItemID", whereIn: seperateItemIds())
                .orderBy("PublishedDate", descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
                  ? SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: circularProgress(),),)
                   : snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0
                   ? // startBuildingCart()
                     Container()
                  : SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index){
                  ItemsModel model = ItemsModel.fromJson(
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>,
                  );

                  if (index == 0)
                  {
                    totalAmount = 0;
                    totalAmount = totalAmount * (model.price! * separateItemQuantityList![index]);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount * (model.price! * separateItemQuantityList![index]);
                  }

                  print("\nTotal Amount = " + totalAmount.toString());

                  if (snapshot.data!.docs.length - 1 == index)
                  {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                      Provider.of<TotalAmount>(context, listen: false).displatTotalAmount(totalAmount.toDouble());
                    });
                  }

                  return CartItemDesign(
                    model: model,
                    context: context,
                    quantity: separateItemQuantityList![index],
                  );
                },
                  childCount: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data!.docs.length : 0,
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I received this problem.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Container:
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderLimitedBox.



RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
The RenderLimitedBox that did not match the expected child type was created by: LimitedBox ← Container ← StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container Container:file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Final%20Year%20Project%202/foodcode_customerapp/lib/screens/ordering/cartscreen.dart:196:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3976:9)
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:4003:6)
#2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6508:25)
#3      _ViewportElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:267:11)
#4      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6268:35)
#5      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5943:5)
#6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6434:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3702:20)
#15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#16     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#18     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#19     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#20     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#21     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#22     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#23     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#24     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#25     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#26     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#4fa94):
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
The RenderErrorBox that did not match the expected child type was created by: ErrorWidget-[#24924] ← Container ← StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Final%20Year%20Project%202/foodcode_customerapp/lib/screens/ordering/cartscreen.dart:185:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3976:9)
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:4003:6)
#2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6508:25)
#3      _ViewportElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:267:11)
#4      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6268:35)
#5      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5943:5)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3702:20)
#14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#15     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#17     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#18     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#19     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#20     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#21     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#22     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#23     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#25     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while rebuilding dirty elements:
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
The RenderErrorBox that did not match the expected child type was created by: ErrorWidget-[#23de1] ← StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#5fc5d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#25ae8] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#00359] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Final%20Year%20Project%202/foodcode_customerapp/lib/screens/ordering/cartscreen.dart:185:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3976:9)
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:4003:6)
#2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6508:25)
#3      _ViewportElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:267:11)
#4      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6268:35)
#5      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5943:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3708:18)
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5125:16)
#9      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#11     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#12     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#13     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#14     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#15     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#16     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#18     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#19     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
The element being rebuilt at the time was index 9 of 21: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
  state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#4fa94
====================================================================================================
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your `StreamBuilder`, u should return
`SliverToBoxAdapter(child:Container())`